# How to access Cloud run service via an Appengine application

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have created a cloud run service I want to access this service in my web application which is running in Appengine ( Flexible Instances ). My web application is in a different google cloud project than cloud run service is created.

I don't want to make cloud run service open to public so I have selected the option "Require Authentication" in Authentication section. And selected "Allow all Traffic" in Ingress section. Also added the Cloud run permission for the appengine service accounts where I have hosted my webapp. After doing these settings I am not able to access the cloud run service (url) via appengine. It is returning Forbidden error.
I am testing the access to url by sshing to the Appengine instance.

So what is the recomended options and settings to make it work ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your configuration is great, but the authentication mechanism is not automatic. You have to add in the header of each request, the `authorization: bearer <token>` header.

The `<token>` is the identity token that you can generate with the App Engine flex service account. Don't forget to add the audience when you generate your identity token (audience=`https://your-service-hash-region.run.app` -> no addition path)

Comment: This can be helpful to complement this answer https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service#acquire-token